# Dividing a css layout vertically

Tags: html, css

I see these types of website popping up everywhere where different sections of the website as you scroll down have a different color and when you resize them, the height of the sections adjust automatically and equally:

https://www.khanacademy.org/
http://www.awwwards.com/best-websites/yay-graphic-design-studio/

I want to make smaller sections as you scroll down differentiated by different colors. But I can't figure out a way to do this without setting an explicit height to the div. What is the right way to do this?

UPDATE: Thank you everyone, for your suggestions. I'm trying to implement this without bootstrap and just with html and css. I'll give fullPage.js a shot and bootstrap if I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly use to Bootstrap's CSS when you need the grid or forms, for example, but the way the second site -- and countless others -- are structured is based on a similar script or the same popular script as this:

#### https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js.

The sections are styled with a your own CSS for the most part. The plugin's CSS is a good starting point. There are many examples to learn from.

Khan uses CSS for the most part. You can use Developer tools in for FireFox or Chrome (addons) and study the styles. Probably a section with a display:table and the content is display:table-cell with a vertical-align:middle -- this is stable on many browsers to put the content in the center vertically. Then the body and html has a height of 100% and each section does as well, but it's really up to situation for that particular project.

Answer (score 0):

A good way to start is using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). It helps with the setting up of your website design. It does most of the nasty work for you. It also depends on the environment you are using. But it should work okay for beginners. By the way, they have some amazing tutorials. You can start by heading over to their CSS section and you will understand how to divide sections and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Bootsrap is a good way to start searching about responsive web sites but i offer you to look at this link, it includes how it happens with your own css or bootstrap.

[w3school page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_responsive.asp)

If you want a quick solution, I guess [that](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy) is what you need

Comment: No w3schools. Just no.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rather "new" css3 property vh witch stands for viewport height. In short the height of the visitors browser height:

see here for compatibility: http://caniuse.com/#search=vh